# Why the sigma algebra generated by a function of a random variable is a subset of the sigma algebra generated by the random variable itself?

Tags: measure-theory, measurable-functions

Could you help me to understand why the sigma algebra generated by a function of a random variable is a subset of the sigma algebra generated by the random variable itself? I think I am missing something about measurability.

Consider the probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ and the measurable space $(\mathbb{R}^d, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^d))$ where $\mathcal{B}(\cdot)$ denotes the Borel sigma algebra. 
Let $X:\Omega\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^d$ be a $(\mathcal{F},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^d))$-measurable random vector.

Let $f(X):\Omega\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^p$ be a $(\mathcal{F},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^p))$-measurable random vector.

Consider the sigma algebra generated by $X$
$$
\sigma(X):=\{X^{-1}(B) \text{ } \forall B\in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^d)\}=\{\omega \in \Omega \text{ s.t. } X(\omega)\in B \text{ } \forall B\in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^d)\}
$$
Consider the sigma algebra generated by $f(X)$

$$
\sigma(f(X)):=\{f(X)^{-1}(C) \text{  }\forall C\in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^p)\}=\{\omega \in \Omega \text{ s.t.} f(X(\omega))\in C \text{ } \forall C \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^p)\}
$$

(1) Why $\sigma(f(X))\subseteq \sigma(X)$?

(2) Consider another real-valued random variable $Y$. Does it follow that $E(Y|X)=E(Y|f(X))$ **if and only if** $\sigma(X)=\sigma(f(X))$?

Comment: Because $f(X)^{-1}(C)=X^{-1}(f^{-1}(C))\in\sigma(X)$ for every Borel set $C$.

Comment: "Does it follow that E(Y|X)=E(Y|f(X)) if and only if σ(X)=σ(f(X))?" Of course not, consider what happens when Y is independent of σ(X).

Comment: Thanks. Can we say that a necessary condition for $E(Y|X)$ to be different from $E(Y|f(X))$ is $\sigma(f(X))\subset \sigma(X)$?

Comment: Sorry, what is $X^{-1}(f^{-1}(C))$? Is $f^{-1}(C)$ something different from $f(X)^{-1}(C)$ I wrote above?

Comment: If you think about what you know about σ(f(X)) and σ(X), the answer to this last question should be direct.

Comment: ?? Please compare "Because f(X)−1(C)=X−1(f−1(C))" and "Is f−1(C) something different from f(X)−1(C) I wrote above?" Then tell me where is this thread going...

Comment: Sorry, my mistake.